# R - Is it possible to optimize or streamline multiple calls to grepl()?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

Working with [NOAA Severe Weather data](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/), which includes a variable `EVTYPE` (event type) describing the type of weather event. The values include many synonyms which I would like to gather under several broader designations. For example there is `TORNADO` but also `ROTATING WALL CLOUD`, `FUNNEL CLOUD`, and `WHIRLWIND` that in a sense describe *relatively* similar events. Without getting into the subtleties of meteorology, I'd like to combine nearly synonymous values like these under a single value name.

So let's say I have the dataset loaded in a dataframe `noaa_clean` and I apply this:

```
tornado <- sapply(as.character(noaa_clean$EVTYPE), 
                   function(x){grepl("^.*TORNAD.*$", x) |
                               grepl("^.*SPOUT.*$", x) |
                               grepl("^.*WHIRL.*$", x) |
                               grepl("^.*FUNNEL.*$", x) |
                               grepl("^.*ROTATING WALL CLOUD.*$", x) |
                               grepl("^.*DUST DEVIL.*$", x)})
noaa_clean[tornado, "EVCAT"] <- "TORNADO"; rm(tornado)
```

It works well, but I have several of these and it takes some time (~5-10min) to run them all. My question is just this: Is there a better way to harness `grepl()` or regex that could make it more efficient?

Comment: The `|` operator works even in regex. You could call `grepl` just once with `grepl("^.*TORNAD|SPOUT|WHIRL|(...).*$", x)` (where the `...` indicate the other possibilities).

Comment: You might also get a speed-up if you switch to `stringi::stri_detect_regex` instead of `grepl`. (And combine the patterns and lose the `sapply` as in MrFlick's answer.)

Comment: You may also want to use word boundaries `\bTORNAD\b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you specifically asked about speed, a test of the various solutions posted in the comments or as answers is:

```
#Initialize vector
x <- sample(c("TORNA", "SPOUT", "WHIRL", "FUNNEL", "ROTATING WALL CLOUD", "DUST DEVIL",
                LETTERS[1:8]), 1e6, replace = TRUE)

#Using separate grepl's
multi_grepl <- function(x) {grepl("TORNAD", x) |grepl("SPOUT", x) |grepl("WHIRL", x) |grepl("FUNNEL", x) | grepl("ROTATING WALL CLOUD", x) |grepl("DUST DEVIL", x)}

#One grepl
one_grepl <- function(x) grepl("TORNAD|SPOUT|WHIRL|FUNNEL|ROTATING WALL CLOUD|DUST DEVIL", x)

#Using stri_detect_regex
detect_regex <- function(x) stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, "TORNAD|SPOUT|WHIRL|FUNNEL|ROTATING WALL CLOUD|DUST DEVIL")

#Original solution with sapply
orig_sapply <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y){grepl("^.*TORNAD.*$", y) |grepl("^.*SPOUT.*$", y) |grepl("^.*WHIRL.*$", y) |grepl("^.*FUNNEL.*$", y) |grepl("^.*ROTATING WALL CLOUD.*$", y) |grepl("^.*DUST DEVIL.*$", y)})

#Using stri_detect_fixed
stri_fixed = function(x) { stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "TORNAD") | stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "SPOUT") | stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "WHIRL") | stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "FUNNEL") | stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "ROTATING WALL CLOUD") | stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "DUST DEVIL") }


#Checking that all these give same answer
identical(multi_grepl(x), one_grepl(x), detect_regex(x), orig_sapply(x), stri_fixed(x))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(multi_grepl(x),
                               one_grepl(x),
                               detect_regex(x),
                               orig_sapply(x),
                               stri_fixed(x), times = 20L)

#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  multi_grepl(x)   724.6716   738.5227   754.2347   747.1441   769.2897   819.9971    20
#    one_grepl(x)   406.7987   410.3197   420.0083   412.1168   426.5932   453.2471    20
# detect_regex(x)   167.4844   170.0834   174.1256   172.7410   177.1546   187.3211    20
#  orig_sapply(x) 47172.3407 47379.8250 47666.7177 47546.2221 47875.9352 48517.2228    20
#   stri_fixed(x)   261.4303   265.9189   270.5816   268.6038   273.2486   288.7071    20
```

It appears that `stri_detect_regex` is the fastest. Interestingly, this changed from the last iteration I tried when I had `^.*` and `.*$` in the `regex`. Credit to @Gregor for pointing this out. Note that your original `sapply` is very slow because it is performing the `grepl` search many times (once for each element). Rather than only once for the whole vector.

---

Lastly, the results for longer individual strings:

```
prefixes <- replicate(1e6, paste0(sample(LETTERS, sample(100:200), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
suffixes <- replicate(1e6, paste0(sample(LETTERS, sample(200:300), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
x_long <- paste0(prefixes, x, suffixes)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(multi_grepl(x_long),
                               one_grepl(x_long),
                               detect_regex(x_long),
                               stri_fixed(x_long), times = 20L)

#Unit: seconds
#                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  multi_grepl(x_long) 27.654274 27.721042 28.194273 27.962656 28.626697 29.909105    20
#    one_grepl(x_long) 11.478831 11.510868 11.775088 11.583650 11.663479 14.318680    20
# detect_regex(x_long)  8.673534  8.729508  8.808797  8.774432  8.878907  9.028005    20
#   stri_fixed(x_long)  4.502196  4.540850  4.609050  4.591879  4.690035  4.750445    20
```

Comment: The use of `^.*` and `.*$` is not necessary and actually counter-productive. I think you'll see faster times without it.

Comment: @MrFlick, I agree. I was trying to use the exact same syntax as the OP, but just change around the structure of the functions. I'll update the examples though

Comment: I think I found a faster solution: `stringi::stri_detect_fixed`. Can't combine the patterns (because it's not regex), but the byte comparison is enough faster that it's almost twice as fast as the `one_grepl` solution. `stri_fixed = function(x)  {
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "TORNAD") |
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "SPOUT") |
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "WHIRL") |
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "FUNNEL") |
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "ROTATING WALL CLOUD") |
  stri_detect_fixed(x, pattern = "DUST DEVIL")
}`

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, I'm also curious how the rankings would compare if the individual strings were longer. I was surprised by your initial rankings because I found `stringi` faster in a recent project where each string was the first 200 words of an email.

Comment: Also, interestingly, when I delete the `^.*` and `.*$` as MrFlick suggests, the ranking changes completely with `detect_regex` on top, my `stri_fixed` method in 2nd, and `one_grepl` in a distant 3rd.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks! This is super helpful. Interesting to see about the `^.*` and `.*$` - I found similar timings. I'll update the examples to use your `stri_fixed` and also to use a larger sample string.

Comment: I'm glad I posted the question; there's a lot of useful insight here. The time on my `sapply` is reflective of how the run time felt.

Comment: The strings being sampled in the dataset are actually quite short, but they are very numerous. `dim(noaa)`  is `[1] 902297     37`. Not exactly big data, but it took minutes to do the formatting. To run the chunk I included in the original question with six separate calls to `grepl` and using `sapply`: ~74secs. Using stri_detect_regex: ~0.69sec. :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions themselves can use `|` as an OR match. You can just do

```
tornado  <- grepl("(TORNAD|SPOUT|WHIRL|FUNNEL|ROTATING WALL CLOUD|DUST DEVIL)", as.character(noaa_clean$EVTYPE))
```

Also note we did not need to use `sapply()` as `grepl` is already a vectorized function in R.

Comment: Are the `^.*` and `.*$` necessary for grepl to look for the occurrences anywhere in the string?

Comment: Depending on your preference, (loading lists of strings from a file for example) you can use `paste0` to create a search string from a vector of words. `grepl(paste0(Words,collapse = '|'),noaa_clean$EVTYPE)`

Comment: @ConnerM. They are not necessary; these type of regular expressions already look anywhere in a string.